# How to unpause the thread in my Android surfaceview?

Tags: android, surfaceview, onresume, onpause

I actually can pause the thread correctly but when I press the unpause button 
it doesn't resume. What am I doing wrong ?

```
public void pause() {

         mRun = false;  

         while (true) {


             try { 
              _thread.join();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) { 

            e.printStackTrace();  
          }
 break;
              }
            _thread = null;
              }

public void unpause() {
              mRun = true;
           _thread = new GameBoardThread(this);
           _thread.start();

          }
```

Comment: What's the error causing force closes? Please post the `logcat`

Comment: don't make new object of thread in unPause method

Comment: without the new object force closes instantly